# General form of "Variation of Parameters"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Recently I found out about the method to solve differential equations called "variation of parameters". However, I have only seen the form of this method for 2$^{nd}$ order DEs, namely

$$u_1'y_1+u_2'y_2=0$$
$$u_1'y_1'+u_2'y_2'=\frac {Q(x)}{a_2}$$

My question is:

*Is there a general form for variation of parameters for the general n$^{th}$ order differential equation?*

Comment: look for Green Function

Answer (score 3):

A general form of variation of parameters works for first-order linear systems 
(and thus in particular $n$'th order linear DE's, which can be translated into first-order linear systems)

$$ X' = A(t) X + b(t)$$

Let $\Psi(t)$ be a fundamental matrix for the homogeneous system, i.e. 
solution of $\Psi' = A(t) \Psi$ with $\Psi(0) = I$.  Write 
$X(t) = \Psi(t) U(t)$.  Then the differential equation becomes

$$ \Psi' U + \Psi U' = A \Psi U + \Psi U' = A \Psi U + b $$
which simplifies to $\Psi U' = b$, so that $U = \int \Psi^{-1} b \; dt + const$.

Comment: In your answer you say "Write $X(t) = \Psi(t)U(t)$", please, could you point me to any bibliography or any clue to what explains this assumption?

Comment: You might look at e.g. Boyce and DiPrima, "Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems", sec. 7.9.

Answer (score 2):

Once you understand the basic idea of the method you can apply it to differential equations of any order.

---

**First Order Case**

First consider the first order differential equation,

$$ a(t)\frac{d y}{dt}+b(t) y= F(t) ,$$

and assume that $y_{\mathrm h}$ solves the homogeneous case (i.e. $F(t)=0$).

We can write any function in the form of the product,

$$ \boxed{f(t) = A(t) \cdot y_{\mathrm h}(t)},$$

if we substitute this product into the differential equation we will be able to exploit the fact that $y_{\mathrm h}$ solves the homogeneous equation to make certain simplifications.

$$a(t) \frac{d}{dt} \left( A(t) y_{\mathrm h}(t) \right) + b(t) \left( A(t) y_{\mathrm h}(t) \right) = F(t),$$

$$\Rightarrow a(t) \left( \frac{dA}{dt}  y_{\mathrm h}(t) + \color{blue}{A(t) \frac{d y_{\mathrm h}}{dt}}
  \right) + \color{blue}{b(t) A(t) y_{\mathrm h}(t) } = F(t),$$

$$\Rightarrow a(t) \frac{dA}{dt}  y_{\mathrm h}(t)  + A(t) \color{blue}{\left[ a(t)  \frac{d y_h}{dt}+b(t) y_{\mathrm h}(t) \right]} = F(t),$$

the blue expression is equal to $\color{blue}{0}$ by the definition of $y_{\mathrm{h}}$ leaving us with,

$$\boxed{a(t) \frac{dA}{dt}  y_{\mathrm h}(t)  = F(t)},$$

If we can solve this equation for $A$ then we will have found a particular solution, in the form of $f$, to the original differential equation.

---

**Example for 1st order case**

As an example of the preceding section, consider the differential equation,

$$ \frac{dy}{dt}+y = \sin(t).$$

The homogeneous solution is $ y_{\mathrm{h}}(t) = y_0 \exp(-t)$.

The differential equation for $A$ is then,

$$ \frac{dA}{dt} = e^t \sin(t),$$

so that we have,

$$\boxed{ A(t) = \int^t e^{t'} \sin(t') dt'} ,$$

and the particular solution to the original equation is given by,

$$ \boxed{f(t) = f_0 e^{-t} \int^t_0 e^{t'} \sin(t') dt'}. $$

---

**Second Order Case**

In the second order case we are solving,

$$ a(t) y'' + b(t) y' + c(t) y = F(t),$$

which generally has two linearly independent solutions ( $y^{(1)}_{\mathrm{h}}$ and $y^{(2)}_{\mathrm{h}}$).

We can then write any function as,

$$ f(t) = A(t) y^{(1)}_h + B(t) y^{(2)}_h(t),$$

substituting this in the differential equation will gives us differential equations for $A$ and $B$ just like in the first order case. For the third order case we write $f(t)$ as a linear combination of three linearly independent homogeneous solutions and the pattern continues for higher order differential equations.

**This answer isn't yet complete I'll be coming back later to fill in some details**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a general form, valid also for linear equations whose coefficients are non-constant.

#### Method

Given an $n$-th order linear differential non homogeneous equation
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) y^{(k)}=b(x),\qquad a_n(x) \neq 0,
$$
and given $y_1(x),\ldots,y_n(x)$, $n$ independent solutions of the associated homogeneous equation, the following linear combination 
$$
y_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y_h(x)
$$
is a solution if the coefficients $c_1(x),\ldots,c_n(x)$ satisfy the following linear system
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y^{(k)}_h(x)=0, \qquad k=0,\ldots,n-2.\\
&\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y^{(n-1)}_h(x)=b(x),
\end{align}
\right.
$$
Solving the system and integrating the resulting $c'_1(x),\ldots,c'_n(x)$, provides the solution.

#### Explanation

Suppose you have a $n$-th order linear differential non homogeneous equation
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) y^{(k)}=b(x),\qquad a_n(x) \neq 0,
$$
and suppose you know $n$ independent solutions of the associated homogeneous equation $y_1(x),\ldots,y_n(x)$.
To find a solution of the non-homogeneous equation, try a solution like the following:
$$
y_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y_h(x).\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
The first derivative is
$$
y'_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y_h(x)+\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y'_h(x),
$$
but we suppose that the $c$'s are such that 
$$
\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y_h(x)=0
$$
i.e., they are non-constant, but behaves like constants in the whole, so that
$$
y'_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y'_h(x).
$$
The second derivative is
$$
y'_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y'_h(x)+\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y''_h(x),
$$
but, again, we suppose that the $c$'s are such that 
$$
\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y'_h(x)=0,
$$
so that
$$
y''_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y''_h(x).
$$
Going on, we have in general
$$
y^{(k)}_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y^{(k)}_h(x),\qquad k=0,\ldots,n-1,
$$
while, for $k=n$ we leave
$$
y^{(n)}_p(x)=\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y^{(n-1)}_h(x)+\sum_{h=1}^nc_h(x)y^{(n)}_h(x),
$$
with the additional conditions on the $c$'s
$$
\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y^{(k)}_h(x)=0, \qquad k=0,\ldots,n-2.\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
Substituting the expression for the derivatives in the differential equation, and remembering that the $y_h(x)$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation, all terms go away, it only remains
$$
\sum_{h=1}^nc'_h(x)y^{(n-1)}_h(x)=b(x),\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
so \eqref{1} is a solution if \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} are satisfied.
Solving this linear system with respect to $c'_h(x)$, and integrating, provides the solution of the non-homogeneous equation we looked for.